# Flutter macos desktop code to send gmail from gmail account

Tags: macos, flutter, gmail, desktop

Does anyone have working code to send gmail through a gmail account from a Flutter Desktop macos project?  I've tried multiple solutions I've found on the internet but when it comes to building desktop apps, it keeps failing.

Comment: do you mean sending email from gmail? if yes try this https://pub.dev/packages/mailer#-readme-tab-

Comment: I believe I need to use oauth2.   Does that package use it?